# HTTPS Communication Failure ABAP

Tags: http, https, abap

I'm working on an application that should be connected to two web applications. The first web application is finished (`http://example.com`). Unfortunately, the second web application utilizing HTTPS (`https://example.com`) threw this error: `Http_Communication_Failure SY-SUBRC = 1`.

Here is my program:

```abap
FORM CHEKCV_LOG_PASS.

    DATA : lv_flag TYPE flag,
           iv_user TYPE CHAR20,
           iv_pass TYPE CHAR20.

            iv_user = 'username'.
           iv_pass = 'Pw1-a83-333'.

  IF sy-subrc IS NOT INITIAL.

  ENDIF.


  CONSTANTS: c_type_get  VALUE 0,
             c_type_post VALUE 1.

  TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_parameter,
           name  TYPE string,
           type  TYPE char1,
           value TYPE string,
         END OF ty_parameter.

  DATA ls_parameter TYPE ty_parameter.
  DATA lt_parameters TYPE TABLE OF ty_parameter.
  DATA lt_fields TYPE tihttpnvp.
  DATA lv_url TYPE string.
  DATA SOAP_ACTION TYPE string.
  DATA lv_uri TYPE string.
  DATA lv_value TYPE string.
  DATA lv_name TYPE string.
  DATA lt_html TYPE TABLE OF string.

  DATA:  lo_client       TYPE REF TO if_http_client,
         lc_content      TYPE string,
         xcontent_clear  TYPE xstring,
         contentencoding TYPE string.

  DATA ls_field     TYPE ihttpnvp.
  DATA lc_url       TYPE string.
  DATA lv_user      TYPE zvrs_veyes_user.
  DATA lv_pass      TYPE char32.

  lv_user = iv_user.
  lv_pass = iv_pass.
  ls_parameter-name = '_username'.
  ls_parameter-value = lv_user.
  ls_parameter-type = c_type_post.
  APPEND ls_parameter TO lt_parameters.
  CLEAR ls_parameter.
  ls_parameter-name = '_password'.
  ls_parameter-value = lv_pass.
  ls_parameter-type = c_type_post.
  APPEND ls_parameter TO lt_parameters.
  CLEAR ls_parameter.

  LOOP AT lt_parameters INTO ls_parameter.
    IF ls_parameter-type = c_type_post.
      ls_field-name  = ls_parameter-name.
      ls_field-value  = ls_parameter-value.
      APPEND ls_field TO lt_fields.
    ELSEIF ls_parameter-type = c_type_get.
      IF lv_url = ''.
        CONCATENATE '?' ls_parameter-name '=' ls_parameter-value
        INTO lv_url.
      ELSE.
        CONCATENATE lv_url '&' ls_parameter-name '=' ls_parameter-value
                                                      INTO lv_url.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.

  lc_url = 'https://Example.com/login_check'.
  CONCATENATE lc_url lv_url INTO lv_url.

  CALL METHOD cl_http_client=>create_by_url
    EXPORTING
      url    = lv_url
    IMPORTING
      client = lo_client
    EXCEPTIONS
      OTHERS = 1.
  IF sy-subrc IS NOT INITIAL.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.
  CALL METHOD lo_client->request->set_header_field
    EXPORTING
      name  = '~request_method'
      value = 'POST'.
******************************************************************

******************************************************************
  LOOP AT lt_fields INTO ls_field.
    lo_client->request->if_http_entity~set_form_field(
    name = ls_field-name value = ls_field-value ).
  ENDLOOP.

   CALL METHOD lo_client->request->set_header_field
    EXPORTING
      name  = '~request_uri'
      value = lv_url.
  lo_client->propertytype_accept_cookie = 1.


  CALL METHOD lo_client->send
    EXCEPTIONS
      http_communication_failure = 1
      http_invalid_state         = 2
      http_processing_failed     = 3
      http_invalid_timeout       = 4
      OTHERS                     = 5.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  ENDIF.

  CALL METHOD lo_client->receive
    EXCEPTIONS
      http_communication_failure = 1
      http_invalid_state         = 2
      http_processing_failed     = 3
      OTHERS                     = 4.
  IF sy-subrc IS NOT INITIAL.

    EXIT.
  ENDIF.
  CALL METHOD lo_client->request->set_header_field
    EXPORTING
      name  = '~request_method'
      value = 'GET'.
  CALL METHOD lo_client->request->set_header_field
    EXPORTING
      name  = '~request_uri'
      value = lc_url.
  CALL METHOD lo_client->send
    EXCEPTIONS
      http_communication_failure = 1
      http_invalid_state         = 2
      http_processing_failed     = 3
      http_invalid_timeout       = 4
      OTHERS                     = 5.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  ENDIF.

  CALL METHOD lo_client->receive *HERE IS THE PROBLEME
    EXCEPTIONS
      http_communication_failure = 1
      http_invalid_state         = 2
      http_processing_failed     = 3
      OTHERS                     = 4.
  IF sy-subrc IS NOT INITIAL.

    EXIT.
  ENDIF.
  lc_content = lo_client->response->get_cdata( ).

endform.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the system variables `SY-MSGxx` for more information on the actual problem. Most likely cause: The server certificate is not signed by any CA that the SAP system is configured to trust. [You might have to add the server and/or CA certificates to the PSE.](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/70/63393c3eb3036be10000000a11402f/frameset.htm) WARNING: Don't do that unless you know what you are doing and have cleared this with your basis admins/infosec officials or you might end up opening security leaks in a critical system.

Comment: In debugger I looked in OP's respective lo_client object for an attribute M_EMESSAGE of the class CL_HTTP_CLIENT, holding a meaningful error message. Not sure if this is the same as populated in sy-msgxxx. But  I agree, due to HTTPS it is very likely a (root) certificate error

Comment: in M_EMESSAGE attribute i have found this message error **SSL handshake with example.com:443 failed: SSSLERR_PEER_CERT_UNTRUSTED (-102)\nThe peer's X.509 Certificate**  i used this tuto to find the missing certificate [https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Security/Troubleshooting+Guide+-+How+to+troubleshoot+the+SSSLERR_PEER_CERT_UNTRUSTED+%28peer+certificate+%28chain%29+is+not+trusted%29+issue] but i don't know if i can import it or i should ask an admin to import it, i thank both of you for your help .