# 401 error when getting file using cl_http_client

Tags: rest, web-services, sharepoint, abap

I am triying to access sharepoint from SAP server using Sharepoint Rest API , but I am getting 401 error even with a sharpoint user that have all needed authorisations:

```
lv_service = 'MYURL/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(''Ressource'')/items'.

cl_http_client=>create_by_url(
    EXPORTING
      url                = lv_service
    IMPORTING
      client             = lo_http_client
    EXCEPTIONS
      argument_not_found = 1
      plugin_not_active  = 2
      internal_error     = 3
      OTHERS             = 4 ).

lo_http_client->authenticate(
    EXPORTING
      username             =   'usr'  " ABAP System, User Logon Name"
      password             =   'password'  ).


lo_http_client->send(
  EXCEPTIONS
   http_communication_failure = 1
   http_invalid_state         = 2 ).

lo_http_client->receive(
    EXCEPTIONS
      http_communication_failure = 1
      http_invalid_state         = 2
      http_processing_failed     = 3 ).
```

In Receive Methode , I Get 401 error:

```
lv_result = lo_http_client->response->get_data( ).
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure `(''Ressource')` is what's actually in your code and not a typo? The code like that should not activate,. And I don't know how sharepoint webservices work, but I doubt it requires strings that begin with `''` and end with `'`.

Comment: But besides that I believe that the answer to your question should either be found in the rest of the server response or somewhere in some log on your Sharepoint server.

Comment: @Philipp , thank you for your answer. (''Ressource') is juste an exemple, it should be ('Ressource')., the link is working correctly when I call it from browser of the same network. But from SAP I have authorisation problem as I explained.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTPS Communication Failure ABAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996153/https-communication-failure-abap)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the http client is set to PUT or **GET** correctly.
I think a GET is required here.

Then the next question is did you generate the link on sharepoint for external access.   Test that url in a browser with dev mode on so you can see what is going on.  Once you are happy there are no redirects etc in the link access, try again with more debugging.

In your code, you can debug the lo_http_client after you try to add the authentication header. See methods like

```
lo_http_client->Request->get_Header_fields.
```

You Can also Debugging to all info returned as Philipp suggested.
lo_http_client->Response->....

You can also check SMICM log to see if any http errors are logged.
Do you SSL errors ?

I would place the document in a non authenticated Public area first.
When the works place the document in folder that is not public and try to authenticate again.

You can use one of the numerous free test tools for building basic URL calls.
Online tools, Browser plug ins, down load apps. whatever.
Make sure you Know what traffic works. Prototyping in ABAP is slow....

I also use ANONYMOUS SSL for such calls.

```
 cl_http_client=>create_by_url(
     EXPORTING
       url                =  l_url
       ssl_id             = 'ANONYM'
     IMPORTING
       client             =  lo_http_client
     EXCEPTIONS
       argument_not_found = 1
       plugin_not_active  = 2
       internal_error     = 3
       OTHERS             = 4
   ).
```

There are just so many things that can go wrong here, if you dont know how to analyze it. It may take a while.

Some other ideas...Not related to the 401 error but may come in handy,
like setting the accepted content types or the call method type to GET

```
  lo_http_client->request->set_header_field(
                                    name  = 'Accept'
                                    value = 'application/json, text/plain, */*').

  lo_http_client->request->set_method(  method = cl_http_entity=>co_request_method_get ).
```